# Free action on integral homology spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, group-actions

**Motivation:** The cyclic group with two elements can freely act on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Note that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is also the Eilenberg–MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Z}, 1)$.

**Question** Let $n\geq 3$. Is there any integral-homology $n$-sphere such that it admits a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action and it is also an Eilenberg–MacLane space $K(G,1)$ for some group $G$?

Comment: Yes, for instance the (3,5,7) Brieskorn sphere of such 3-d manifold.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that by a (integral) homology $n$-sphere you mean an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ which has $H_*(M)\cong H_*(S^n)$.  (One can consider instead of manifolds more general CW complexes.) According to [Thurston's version of the Hopf Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_conjecture#Thurston_conjecture_on_aspherical_manifolds_(extension_of_Hopf%27s_conjecture)), if $M$ is a closed aspherical manifold of dimension $2k$ then
$$
(-1)^k \chi(M)  \ge 0.
$$
In particular, if $k$ is odd, then, conjecturally, $\chi(M)\le 0$. Such a manifold cannot be a homology sphere.

On the other hand, there is an abundant supply of closed aspherical 3-manifolds which are integral 3-spheres. Early examples of these are given by *Seifert manifolds* whose base-orbifold has nonpositive Euler characteristic. For every Seifert manifold $M$ whose Seifert fibration is orientable, we have a canonical $S^1$-action on $M$, corresponding to the rotation of the fibers. This action is not free if there are singular fibers. However, suppose that *Seifert invariants* $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ of singular fibers are all such that $\alpha_i$ is coprime with  $n$, then the order $n$ rotation of the fiber acts freely on $M$. It remains to find examples $M$ which are integral homology spheres. These are given, for instance, by Brieskorn manifolds $M(p,q,r)$ for which $p, q, r$ are all coprime. A very nice exposition of Brieskorn 3-manifolds is given in Milnor's paper

*Milnor, John W.*, [On the 3-dimensional Brieskorn manifolds M(p,q,r)](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/milnbries.pdf), Knots, Groups, 3-Manif.; Pap. dedic. Mem. R. H. Fox, 175-225 (1975). [ZBL0305.57003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0305.57003).

Taking $p, q, r$ which are all odd and coprime (say, $3, 5, 7$) yields an example of a 3-dimensional integral homology sphere which is aspherical and admits a free involution.

I am sure there are other examples in all odd dimensions, but sorting this out would take some work.

I am not sure what happens if you allow arbitrary CW complexes as your $K(G,1)$'s, I suspect that you get examples in even dimensions as well.

There is a separate interesting question regarding which finite groups admit free actions on integral homology spheres. For some results in this direction, see

*Milnor, John W.*, [**Groups which act on (S^ n) without fixed points**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2372566), Am. J. Math. 79, 623-630 (1957). [ZBL0078.16304](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0078.16304).

and

*Wall, C. T. C.*, Free actions of finite groups on spheres, Algebr. geom. Topol., Stanford/Calif. 1976, Proc. Symp. Pure Math., Vol. 32, Part 1, 115-124 (1978). [ZBL0407.57031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0407.57031).

Comment: Thank you very mych for your time and elaboration! Do you aware of exsictance of such a space when  n is an odd integer greater than 3 or you just have a strong feeling about existance of those spaces? What if we were intrested about aspherical finite free z_2-complexes whose fundamental groups are non-trivial perfect groups? Do you know any construction in this case for other values of n?

Comment: @123...: I do not have a specific constructions but I would look at higher-dimensional analogues of Seifert manifolds, including infra-nil manifolds.